# Imported appcompat library has errors

Tags: java, android, xml

I recently updated my SDK, downloaded newest API 21, deleted support library because appcompat project was not present, installed it, and I imported appcompat, just like Google wants me to do it (copied to my workspace, added every jar to build path, configured build path etc.).

Now I am getting errors in `android-support-v7-appcompat -> res -> values-v21 -> styles_base.xml`, at line:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
        parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
</style>
```

The error is:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

go in the project->properties of your appcompat project
change `target=android-19` to `target=android-21`
all your projects using this library also need to be on `target=android-21`

Comment: i dont know then, thats how i got it fixed for me. anyway there is no source files, i guess it can only come from manifest or properties. or your eclipse configuration

Comment: Did you solved this probleme? The new v7 library kill my apps.

Comment: I do not remember how exactly I solved this in that app, I edited a lot of resources etc. But today I had similliar problem with support library, that was annoying as hell so I changed definition of this error in android lint error checking from error to warning :D Not the best but did the job, app can be signed, published and works...

Comment: This will fix the error in the XML file..Even though you may be using a different API version.

Answer (score 1):

Right-Click on the appcompat project folder and open "properties".
Go to "Android" section and check "Android 5.0" as the project build target
apply it and enjoy :)

Comment: I got this error while doing that: Parsing Data for android-21 failed
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: Try installing JDK 1.8 and reload Eclipse.